# Chaining SSH tunnels for forwarding HTTPS?

Tags: ssh, firewall

I have a firewall, `Host A`, that is accessible over the internet. It performs NAT for the hosts behind it.

Behind this firewall, there is `Host B`, which is accessible via SSH from the firewall device.

There is also a second host, `Host C` which is listening on HTTPS (Port 443) - however, this is only accessible from `Host B`, and not from `Host A`.

I can SSH from my computer to `Host A`, then from there I can SSH to `Host B`, and from there I can use `elinks` to connect to the HTTPS server on `Host C`. The web app doesn't work very well over that, though...lol.

My question is - is there a way I can setup some kind of chained SSH tunnel, that will allow me to access the web server on `Host C` from my client?

```
                +
                |
                |
+-------------+ |  +-------------+   +-------------+   +---------------+
|             | |  |             |   |             |   |               |
|    Client   +---->  Host A     +---> Host B      +-->+  Host C       |
|             | |  |  (Firewall) |   | (Linux SoC) |   |  HTTPS Server |
|             | |  |             |   |             |   |               |
+-------------+ |  +-------------+   +-------------+   +---------------+
                |
                |
                +
```

Comment: Dear God. I don't know if this can be done, and I wouldn't even make the attempt. I'd just use a VPN.

Comment: This is the dome style: if i understand you right, is Host A just a "router" - so we dont care;
on host B (i.e.: debian/ubuntu) apt install ziproxy
i prefer putty, so i ssh into host B and set a proxy on client and a portfowarding
then i just you my browser and can access Host C over host B with my browser
easier as setup a vpn

Answer (score 0):

From Host A

```
root@HostA:~# ssh -f user@HostB -L 443:HostC:443
```

Try with this.

Then point your browser at https://hosta , hoping that port 443 is not filtered by firewall

Comment: For many webservers, and certainly with SSL it is necessary to have the right hostname, so you have to tweak your DNS so that from the client the hostname for the website on C points to host A.